# External javascript file does not load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a flip clock similar to https://codepen.io/blucube/pen/pgqRKr/ .  The javascript is written as such that if the code runs then the page should display the current time with a flick on the seconds box which keep changing every second. However, the page doesn't display anything reason being the javascript file doesn't load. Here is my code:

```js
function flipTo(digit, n) {
  var current = digit.attr('data-num');
  digit.attr('data-num', n);
  digit.find('.front').attr('data-content', current);
  digit.find('.back, .under').attr('data-content', n);
  digit.find('.flap').css('display', 'block');
  setTimeout(function() {
    digit.find('.base').text(n);
    digit.find('.flap').css('display', 'none');
  }, 350);
}

function jumpTo(digit, n) {
  digit.attr('data-num', n);
  digit.find('.base').text(n);
}

function updateGroup(group, n, flip) {
  var digit1 = $('.ten' + group);
  var digit2 = $('.' + group);
  n = String(n);
  if (n.length == 1) n = '0' + n;
  var num1 = n.substr(0, 1);
  var num2 = n.substr(1, 1);
  if (digit1.attr('data-num') != num1) {
    if (flip) flipTo(digit1, num1);
    else jumpTo(digit1, num1);
  }
  if (digit2.attr('data-num') != num2) {
    if (flip) flipTo(digit2, num2);
    else jumpTo(digit2, num2);
  }
}

function setTime(flip) {
  var t = new Date();
  updateGroup('hour', t.getHours(), flip);
  updateGroup('min', t.getMinutes(), flip);
  updateGroup('sec', t.getSeconds(), flip);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  setTime(false);
  setInterval(function() {
    setTime(true);
  }, 1000);

});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #85D8CE;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #085078, #85D8CE);
}

.digit {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 15vw;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1vw;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Oswald, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11vw;
}

.base {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #333;
}

.flap {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 1vw 1vw 0 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flap::before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

.flap.front::before,
.flap.under::before {
  top: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.flap.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flap.back::before {
  top: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateZ(180deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateZ(180deg);
}

.flap.over {
  z-index: 2;
}

.flap.under {
  z-index: 1;
}

.flap.front {
  -webkit-animation: flip-down-front 300ms ease-in both;
  animation: flip-down-front 300ms ease-in both;
}

.flap.back {
  -webkit-animation: flip-down-back 300ms ease-in both;
  animation: flip-down-back 300ms ease-in both;
}

.flap.under {
  -webkit-animation: fade-under 300ms ease-in both;
  animation: fade-under 300ms ease-in both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flip-down-front {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    background-color: #a6a6a6;
    color: black;
  }
}

@keyframes flip-down-front {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    background-color: #a6a6a6;
    color: black;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes flip-down-back {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(0deg);
    background-color: #a6a6a6;
    color: black;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg);
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
  }
}

@keyframes flip-down-back {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(0deg);
    background-color: #a6a6a6;
    color: black;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg);
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-under {
  0% {
    background-color: #a6a6a6;
    color: black;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-under {
  0% {
    background-color: #a6a6a6;
    color: black;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
  }
}

.clock {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70vw;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15vw;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-perspective: 100vw;
  perspective: 100vw;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.clock .digit {
  margin-right: 1vw;
}

.clock .digit:nth-child(2n+2) {
  margin-right: 3.5vw;
}

.clock .digit:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clock">

  <div class="digit tenhour">
    <span class="base"></span>
    <div class="flap over front"></div>
    <div class="flap over back"></div>
    <div class="flap under"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="digit hour">
    <span class="base"></span>
    <div class="flap over front"></div>
    <div class="flap over back"></div>
    <div class="flap under"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="digit tenmin">
    <span class="base"></span>
    <div class="flap over front"></div>
    <div class="flap over back"></div>
    <div class="flap under"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="digit min">
    <span class="base"></span>
    <div class="flap over front"></div>
    <div class="flap over back"></div>
    <div class="flap under"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="digit tensec">
    <span class="base"></span>
    <div class="flap over front"></div>
    <div class="flap over back"></div>
    <div class="flap under"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="digit sec">
    <span class="base"></span>
    <div class="flap over front"></div>
    <div class="flap over back"></div>
    <div class="flap under"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: And you see no errors in the console?

Comment: The codepen uses jQuery which `<script>` you can't see in the code because it's configured in "Settings". | If you open the console you will probably see a "$ is not defined" error, $ is jQuery.

Comment: Press the "run code snippet" button.. your code works fine.. you probably just forgot to add jquery or something.